# Unit regular elements

Tags: ring-theory

I am looking for various examples of non-regular rings whose every regular element is unit regular.  In other words, a ring $R$, $R$ is not regular but for which if $a\in R$ is regular, then $a$  is unit regular.

Answer (score 0):

Every [local ring with nil radical](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?has=55&has=109&lacks=12) is such a ring. Elements are split between nilpotent elements (which are obviously not regular) and units (which are obviously unit regular.) The link above points to several such rings.